# Calling a function not working in react constructor

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a function in a react constructor:

```
class CardRow extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("constructor works");
        console.log(withFetching);
        console.log(noticeAPI);
        console.log(promoIter);
        withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Swatch />
                <ScrollMenu data={list} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CardRow;
```

All of the functions show correctly when I `console.log` them, as well as the "constructor works!" text displaying, however for some reason the promoIter function doesn't execute.

```
const promoIter = ({ data, isLoading, error }) => {
    console.log("test");
    return null;
}
```

withFetching looks like this:

```
const withFetching = (url) => (Comp) =>
  class WithFetching extends Component {
```

Basically, I am trying to call another API to build some additional structure when an earlier call is made.

Comment: The result of `withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)` is a component. You never use it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Then would I just pass it in as <withFetching /> to the render portion? How would I pass the arguments to it?

Comment: You seem to use a HOC ```withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)``` that returns a component. You can assign that component to a const like ```const ComponentFromFetch = withFetching(noticeAPI)(promoIter)``` in the constructor and then use <ComponentFromFetch />  wherever you like.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander As props. And noticeAPI is constant, isn't it?

Comment: noticeAPI is constant, but that argument is filled with whatever API I am calling